# Anime where pilot phases through a mountain to reach his mecha

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, anime

Can anybody help identify this anime series with a fighting robot? Two specifics stood out in my mind (which hopefully doesn't indicate my remembering two different series):

1. The boy who controlled the robot did so by phasing through the rock of a mountain that the robot was in.
2. The bad/guy witch had a face that would split apart down the centre. I think it revealed a smaller version of the bad guy/witch when it opened.

My guess is going to be late 70's early 80s. It was on US Broadcast TV. So likely it was dubbed into English.

Comment: Do you remember any details about the robot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your description I'm fairly sure it's [UFO Robot Grendizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grendizer). I believe it was aired in the US as Grandizer (*a* instead of *e*) and was part of the "Force Five" serires.

[image: picture of Grendizer]

When the bad guys attacked, the hero (farm hand Daisuke) would rush to Grendizer who was hidden inside a cave and jump into the cockpit while transforming into his real identity as the exiled alien prince Duke Fleed. Here's a youtube of that scene from the Italian version:

One of the major bad guys was General Gandal who (in the first season at least) housed his minuscule wife inside his head.

[image: picture of General Gandal]

Comment: I am absolutely certain that you are right about General Gandal. That image is exactly as I remember it. Going to YouTube and looking at several episodes, the transformation of Daisuke is not what I am remembering. I remember seeing the boy jump off a motorcycle, land back against a mountain and dissolve in. This is very close and. Will look for a few more to be sure.

Comment: @AndreiFreeman - The bike scene (as user13095 stated) does indeed look like it came from Barve Raideen. So perhaps you are remembering two series? I know there was a lot of anime mashups in the 70's and 80's aired as one show in the US. Link to Raideen intro with a similar bike scene:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SloHs5O4S48

Comment: I wish I could give both answers the check mark. But you supplied pictures and video links. I'd love to find some of these episodes in full to watch.

Comment: Fan subtitled versions of both shows exist on the web

Comment: The linked Youtube video seemed to be japanese despite the italian URL at the top. This one is in french (better quality also and a scene a little bit enhanced): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-k2K0O8A-0. By the way, it was called *Goldorak* in french (and perhaps other languages too)

Comment: @AndreiFreeman One full episode (in french again): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rG_8DTdm68M&t=2m9s to see if it's the right one.

Comment: @LudoMC - Grendizer is something of a childhood favorite of mine which I saw dubbed in Arabic, so I've never actually seen the Japanese version. Although I did know about the French naming.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds a lot like Brave Raideen, which has a little kid that phases to get inside of Raideen's head. It's from the 1970s, and is very Japanese giant robot crazy.

All the details you can handle at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_Raideen) and [this blog](http://letsanime.blogspot.com/2008/11/go-go-raideen.html).

As was mentioned above, if you can think of anything more that would be helpful. A lot of the giant robots from that time period emerge from stuff and have some person or being fly into their head.

Comment: This link mentions the Shogun Warriors, which I'm pretty much 95% sure was the series that I saw it on. The series looks like a compilation of anime series; which less credibility that I may be remembering two different shows. I wish there were more pictures of those shows. Also, your blog link seems to be the same as your Wiki link.

Comment: @AndreiFreeman I fixed the second link, it now goes to the correct site. Shogun Warriors was indeed a sort of mish-mash of various anime and manga.

Comment: If I am not mistaken Shogun Warriors was a part of Force Five which showed a mix of 5 different shows one on each day of the week or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be Tranzor Z? (aka [Mazinger Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazinger_Z)) I know that the villain had a henchman that was 1/2 woman/man split down the middel of his/her face and the robot lived in an underground cave. I realize that it is somewhat different than the things you recalled, but some similarities and aired in the US during the correct time period. Some pics [here](http://mazinworld.net/Mazinger.html) to jog your memory.

Comment: I remember Tranzor Z with the kids space-ship that docked into the head. The kid in the one I'm remembering has a younger feel and for some reason I think brown hair. He didn't have that "Derek Wildstar" hero look of the 70s/80s

Answer (score 0):

The series I remember with a giant robot could be [Mobile Suit Gundam Wing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0176379/), A squadron of giant robot pilots of a beleaguered Earth colony bring the war to their oppressive home planet.

Comment: It's got big robots, but how does it match the rest of his post?

Comment: Thanks for the down vote. You should know that the question has been changed *after* I answered and the new details didn't match. I was looking for another anime.